# Sitecore 8.2 Mongo Connectionstrings VS Sitecore 9.3 xConnect Connectionstrings

Tags: xdb, upgrade, mongodb

Sitecore XP version 8.2 comes with following MongoDB databases with connection string:

1. analytics
2. tracking.live
3. tracking.history
4. tracking.contact

We are planning to upgrade Sitecore 8.2 mongo to Sitecore 9.3 mongo.

Couple of questions came to my mind

1. How to use the above mongo databases in Sitecore 9.3 Xconnect.
2. Does mongo db schema will be differ in sitecore 8.2 mongo and sitecore 9.3 mongo?

any help or suggestion would be greatly helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to use proper version of Sitecore xDB Data Migration Tool https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_xDB_Data_Migration_Tool.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The [installation guide for Sitecore XP 9.3.0](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_xDB_Data_Migration_Tool.aspx) describes how to configure the MongoDB provider for xConnect.
To continue using the MongoDB xDB Collection database provider with Sitecore XP 9.3.0, you
must upgrade your existing MongoDB instance to version 4.0.5 – 4.0.10.
To upgrade the xDB Collection database there are some scripts that you need to run. These scripts are mentioned in the upgrade Sitecore manuals.

If you want to migrate the Analytics data from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9.3 you need to use [xDB Data Migration Tool](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_xDB_Data_Migration_Tool.aspx)

So, as a conclusion, the old schema and data cannot be re-used in Sitecore 9.3 you need to migrate it.